# PHP wildcard character in the string

Tags: php

I'm echoing embedded style of div. In that style I'm setting background image. I know the image file name, but I cant be certain about file type since it can be jpeg, jpg, gif or png.

Like in this example, it could have been png image.

```
if(file_exists("images/img_".$loggedInUser->user_id.".jpeg")){
  echo "style='background-image: url(\"images/img_".$loggedInUser->user_id.".jpeg\");'";
}
```

Is it possible to use some kind of wildcard character for extension here?

Comment: If it's only 4 possibilities why not just use an `if else` and list all 4 options?

Comment: Why don't you just *store* the file name? It seems pointless to start guessing every time you need to display a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multiple files match the pattern then the first one will be used:

```
if($file = glob("images/img_{$loggedInUser->user_id}.*")) {
    echo "style='background-image: url(\"{$file[0]}\");'";
}
```

Tweak it if you want a different behavior for multiple file.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard's can be used with [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob).

Example:

```
$pics = glob("images/img_" . $loggedInUser->user_id . ".*");
if (isset($pics[0])) {
    // file exists
}
```

[`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/fnmatch) can be useful.

Alternative way, using kinda Manager `class`:

```
class Image {
    private $user;
    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getPicture() {
        $path = glob("images/img_" . $this->user . ".*");
        if (isset($pics[0]) {
            return "style='background-image: url(" . $pics[0] . ");'";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$pic = new Image($loggedInUser->user_id);
echo $pic->getUserPicture();
```